# implement multiple screen and folders

Tags: android

Hi guys i don't know if this is correct.
I want implement support multiple screen.
I have created in my project

Layout-
Layout-land
Layout-small
Layout-large
Layout-sw230dp
Layout-sw400dp
Layout-sw720dp
and put all my layouts in every folder.

My app include the support for 2.x. gingerbread. 
There is a simple solution for implement multiple screen?

I know that Gingerbread  get the layouts only from layout Layout-small abd layout-large!

I I have need to edit all layouts in every folder.
Can you make me a exanple?step by step?
Please guys :( :(

Thank u

Comment: "Layout" is not the same as "layout"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example at android developer website and states:
if you have a different layout on orientation change you also need to have **land** and **port** modifier on the folder

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

[Click here for more info](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Thank u! Yes but i have read... when i run my app in android 2.3, android get layout into the folders layout-small / large / xlarge... but when my app run into ICS or JB get the layout into the folder layout-sw320dp / sw480dp / .... is correct?